# Sending email from webpage using PHP

Tags: php, email, smtp

On my page when I'm trying to send an email to my own personal email it says

> Notice: Undefined variable: use_smtp in form-handler.php on line 49
> Error. Try again

and when I look to my code I can't find where it's wrong.

This is the code:

```
<?php
include('SMTPClass.php');

$use_smtp=0; // $use_smtp=false;
$use_smtp=1; // $use_smtp=true;
$emailto = 'benfica.goed3@gmail.com';
// retrieve from parameters
$emailfrom = isset($_POST["email"]) ? $_POST["email"] : "";
$nocomment = isset($_POST["nocomment"]) ? $_POST["nocomment"] : "";
$subject = 'Email de EcoLover';
$message = '';
$response = '';
$response_fail = 'There was an error verifying your details.';

    // Honeypot captcha
    if($nocomment == '') {
        $params = $_POST;
        foreach ( $params as $key=>$value ){
            if(!($key == 'ip' || $key == 'emailsubject' || $key == 'url' || $key == 'emailto' || $key == 'nocomment' || $key == 'v_error' || $key == 'v_email')){
                $key = ucwords(str_replace("-", " ", $key));
                
                if ( gettype( $value ) == "array" ){
                    $message .= "$key: \n";
                    foreach ( $value as $two_dim_value )
                    $message .= "...$two_dim_value<br>";
                }else {
                    $message .= $value != '' ? "$key: $value\n" : '';
                }
            }
        }   
    $response = sendEmail($subject, $message, $emailto, $emailfrom);
        
    } else {
        $response = $response_fail;
    }
echo $response;
// Run server-side validation
function sendEmail($subject, $content, $emailto, $emailfrom) {
    global $use_smtp;
$from = $emailfrom;
$response_sent = 'Obrigado pela sua sugestão.';
$response_error = 'Erro. Tente novamente';
$subject =  filter($subject);
$url = "Origin Page: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$ip = "IP Address: ".$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
$message = $content."\n$ip\r\n$url";
// Validate return email & inform admin
$emailto = filter($emailto);

// Setup final message
$body = wordwrap($message);
if($use_smtp){
    $SmtpServer = 'SMTP SERVER';
    $SmtpPort = 'SMTP PORT';
    $SmtpUser = 'SMTP USER';
    $SmtpPass = 'SMTP PASSWORD';
    $to = $emailto;
    $SMTPMail = new SMTPClient ($SmtpServer, $SmtpPort, $SmtpUser, $SmtpPass, $from, $to, $subject, $body);
    $SMTPChat = $SMTPMail->SendMail();
    $response = $SMTPChat ? $response_sent : $response_error;
    
} else {
    // Create header
    $headers = "From: $from\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\r\n";
    // Send email
    $mail_sent = @mail($emailto, $subject, $body, $headers);
    $response = $mail_sent ? $response_sent : $response_error;
    
}
return $response;
}
    // Remove any un-safe values to prevent email injection
function filter($value) {
$pattern = array("/\n/", "/\r/", "/content-type:/i", "/to:/i", "/from:/i", "/cc:/i");
$value = preg_replace($pattern, "", $value);
return $value;
}

exit;
?>
```

Now the code works but the code of the other page is now giving me error like:

> Warning: fsockopen() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/EcoLover/SMTPClass.php on line 29
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: talk in /opt/lampp/htdocs/EcoLover/SMTPClass.php on line 61 Error. Try again.

Here is the code of the other page:

```
<?php

class SMTPClient
{

function SMTPClient ($SmtpServer, $SmtpPort, $SmtpUser, $SmtpPass, $from, $to, $subject, $body)
{

$this->SmtpServer = $SmtpServer;
$this->SmtpUser = base64_encode ($SmtpUser);
$this->SmtpPass = base64_encode ($SmtpPass);
$this->from = $from;
$this->to = $to;

$this->subject = $subject;
$this->body = $body;

if ($SmtpPort == "") 
{
$this->PortSMTP = 25;
    }else{
$this->PortSMTP = $SmtpPort;
}
    }

function SendMail ()
{

if ($SMTPIN = fsockopen ($this->SmtpServer, $this->PortSMTP)) 
{

       fputs ($SMTPIN, "EHLO ".$HTTP_HOST."\r\n");  
       $talk["hello"] = fgets ( $SMTPIN, 1024 ); 
               
       fputs($SMTPIN, "auth login\r\n");
       $talk["res"]=fgets($SMTPIN,1024);
        fputs($SMTPIN, $this->SmtpUser."\r\n");
        $talk["user"]=fgets($SMTPIN,1024);
        
        fputs($SMTPIN, $this->SmtpPass."\r\n");
        $talk["pass"]=fgets($SMTPIN,256);
                
       fputs ($SMTPIN, "MAIL FROM: <".$this->from.">\r\n");  
       $talk["From"] = fgets ( $SMTPIN, 1024 );  
       fputs ($SMTPIN, "RCPT TO: <".$this->to.">\r\n");  
       $talk["To"] = fgets ($SMTPIN, 1024); 
       
       fputs($SMTPIN, "DATA\r\n");
        $talk["data"]=fgets( $SMTPIN,1024 );
       
        fputs($SMTPIN, "To: <".$this->to.">\r\nFrom: <".$this->from.">\r\nSubject:".$this->subject."\r\n\r\n\r\n".$this->body."\r\n.\r\n");
        $talk["send"]=fgets($SMTPIN,256);
       
       //CLOSE CONNECTION AND EXIT ... 
       
       fputs ($SMTPIN, "QUIT\r\n");  
       fclose($SMTPIN); 
     //  
}

return $talk;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Its a notice error I assume it should be avoided by error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); unless emails are not working.

Comment: Don't just hide notices, unless you're happy producing code that's full of errors. Which is line 49?

Comment: if($use_smtp == '1'){

Comment: Would you append the new code to the question? And you haven't added this line have you `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); ` (you shouldn't)?

Comment: I'm sorry @Popnoodles for being a noob. but are you saying the new code??

Comment: no but where do i add that line??

Comment: You don't add that line - it will hinder progress. Please edit the question and, at the bottom, add the latest version of the code that you gave previously, having made the suggested changes.

Comment: @Popnoodles where do i add error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);??

Comment: **You don't add that line of code anywhere!** You were given bad advice and that WILL NOT solve the problem. See **this** answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/22440194/822711

Comment: @Popnoodles i've added the line after $emailto = filter($emailto);

Comment: **SMH Adding that line will hinder progress. It is not a solution. It is bad advice** Stop and read my answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22439839/sending-email-from-webpage-to-using-php/22440194#22440194

Comment: @Popnoodles thnx that problem is solved but now i have a problem in that include file

Comment: Can you please clarify what changes you made to the code?

Comment: ok i'll add the code new code

Comment: it now gives me this error: Warning: fsockopen() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/EcoLover/SMTPClass.php on line 29

Notice: Undefined variable: talk in /opt/lampp/htdocs/EcoLover/SMTPClass.php on line 61
Erro. Tente novamente

Comment: Please add all edits, error messages, and everything else to the question. Once you have done that, consider deleting some of your comments above (especially where they are duplicated by your question edits) - so that getting the state of the query for new readers is a trivial process.

Comment: I give up, why have you added both these lines when you want it to be 0? `$use_smtp=0; // $use_smtp=false; $use_smtp=1; // $use_smtp=true`. Remove this line `$use_smtp=1; // $use_smtp=true` and your next problem is for another question, though it may not exist.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're setting

```
$use_smtp = '0';
```

outside of this function and the function doesn't know about it

```
function sendEmail($subject, $content, $emailto, $emailfrom) {
```

Two options: make it global

```
function sendEmail($subject, $content, $emailto, $emailfrom) {
    global $use_smtp;
    // etc
```

or pass it to the  function

```
function sendEmail($subject, $content, $emailto, $emailfrom, $use_smtp) {
//                                                            ^ add this
```

like so

```
sendEmail($subject, $content, $emailto, $emailfrom, $use_smtp);
//                                                   ^ add this
```

**Please DO NOT add this line** `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);` as someone else suggested. Without the notices you would have not known instantly on which line the problem was. If you are new to programming it is essential that you are given as much info as possible.

**Aside:**

You can use a boolean or 0 and 1, `$use_smtp` doesn't need to be a string.

```
$use_smtp=0; // $use_smtp=false;
$use_smtp=1; // $use_smtp=true;
```

And you don't need to check that it's equal to '1'. 
`0`, `'0'`, and `false` are all false.

```
if ($use_smtp)
```

Answer (score -1):

as I took from your comment that SMTP is working and this notice is bugging you. You are working in environment with full error logging / debugging / etc... add error_reporting in start of your PHP file, like this:

```
   <?PHP
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

---

EDIT:

you should make global $use_smtp in your function. Sorry I oversighted this.

```
function sendEmail($subject, $content, $emailto, $emailfrom) {
global $use_smtp;
```

Comment: Sidstar i added the code and the result whas i got error but how can i make it work so i can send the email??

Comment: ok if i post the smtp code can  you plzz see where it has an error ?? im a noob in php programming and im still learning

Comment: Please do not just hide notices. If you had them hidden you wouldn't not have known that there was a problem with your code. They problem is highlighted by the notice.